# Factorial of binary numbers, Not as it seems

Tags: binary, numbers, permutation, factorial

Start off factorial of `4` is 24.
Which means 24 different permutations possible.
But I seem to keep getting only 16 different permutations for 4 different binary numbers.
Seems its like 4x4=16

I did this by hand maybe I missed one.

1= 0, 0, 0, 0
2= 0, 0, 0, 1
3= 0, 0, 1, 0
4= 0, 0, 1, 1

5= 0, 1, 0, 0
6= 0, 1, 0, 1
7= 0, 1, 1, 0
8= 0, 1, 1, 1

9=  1, 0, 0, 0
10= 1, 0, 0, 1
11= 1, 0, 1, 0
12= 1, 0, 1, 1

13= 1, 1, 0, 0
14= 1, 1, 0, 1
15= 1, 1, 1, 0
16= 1, 1, 1, 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **24** different patterns, it requires at least 5 bits in binary to represent the information. Only 16 patterns are forming because of **2^4** not 4*4. You just add another bit position to the numbers and your problem will be solved. I mean something like :

```
1= 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
2= 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
.......
.......    
15= 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
16= 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
.....
24=1, 0, 1, 1, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of "permutation with repetition". The formula is n^r; factorial is used for "permutation without repetition". In each digit position of the 4-digit binary numbers, there can be 2 different possibilities; 0 and 1. So n is 2. And there are 2 possibilities for each of the 4 digits; therefore r is 4. 2^4 computes to 16.

Comment: `The formula is n^r; factorial is used for "permutation without repetition".`  You mean with repetition?

Answer (score 0):

Factorial works in these type of things when the number of things you can choose decreases each time, in order to find the number of permutations.  i.e. I have 7 colored t-shirts and I want to find the number of different weeks I can make by wearing a different shirt each day of the week.

The first day I have 7 shirts to choose from.  The next day I have 6, because I don't want to wear any shirt twice, and so on.  So the number of permutations is 7!

However! If I allow myself to wear a shirt on more than one day of a week, then its now 7x7x7x7x7x7x7 or 7^7.

So, basically in the first solution, the options later in the permutation tree are dependent upon what I have chosen in previous trees.  In the second solution, it is independent.  If I wear Red on Monday, I can still wear it Tuesday.  So I have 7 options day one and 7 options day 2...n=7.

So, you were in the right ballpark to get on the right track, you just found the swimming pool instead.  In your example, your next permutation is independent of what you chose the first time.  So 2^4 is appropriate.  The Factorial solution would be saying that you can't reuse 1 if you have already, your set is constrained and your choices are dependent. Binary(1,0)! = 1,0 and 0,1 or 2! (2 choices 1 or 0).

This is an odd question to be sure though, it doesn't really mean anything.  It's like you took 2 sort of basic ideas and mushed them together in your excitement to nerd out (Binary!).   I can just imagine someone day dreaming about math but without really a strong past in it, (but maybe a future...)  I don't know.